# Assign string held in an object variable to a string property of a dynamic (C#)

Tags: c#, dynamic, c#-4.0, dynamic-language-runtime

I know its a bit of a mouthful and may not be totally understandable. So here is an example of what I am trying to do.

```
public class TypeWithString
{
    public string MyString { get; set; }
}

string s = "We Want Moshiach Now";
TypeWithString tws = new TypeWithString();
object o = s;
dynamic d = tws;
d.MyString = o;
```

This code surprisingly generates an error `RuntimeBinderException: Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'string'`.
Even though `MyString` is of type `string` and what is being held in `o` is a `string`.

is this a bug or a shortcoming in the DLR?

Is there a way to get around it?

If I do not know the type ahead of time. But I do know that it complies with duck typing. i.e. I know that it implements an unwritten interface. Is there anyway I can assign one variable to the other when they really are the correct type?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is expected. The compiler knows the type of `o` is `object`, so it records a dynamic action of "try to find a property called `MyString` and then try to assign a value of type `object` to it" - it could do that if there were an implicit conversion of `object` to `string`, but there isn't. Note that the only part of your statement which is dynamic is the *target* of it... so that's the only bit which is treated dynamically. At execution time, the "execution-time compiler" will effectively say, "What's the actual type of the value of `d`? Ah, it's TypeWithString... now, what would happen if we had:

```
TypeWithString tmpD = (TypeWithString) d;
tmpD.MyObject = o;
```

... and what would happen would be a compile-time error.

If you want it to behave dynamically in the value as well, just use `dynamic` instead of `object` for the value you assign:

```
string s = "We Want Moshiach Now";
TypeWithString tws = new TypeWithString();
dynamic o = s;
dynamic d = tws;
d.MyString = o;
```

This time, the "execution-time compiler" will ask itself for the actual type of both `d` *and* `o` values, and imagine code like this:

```
TypeWithString tmpD = (TypeWithString) d;
string tmpO = (string) o; // Actual type is string at execution time
tmpD.MyObject = tmpO;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could always try `d.MyString = o as string;` which will cast (without throwing) o to a string or null if cast doesnt exist.

Comment: B"H

I don't know ahead of time what it is going to be. otherwise I would have just stored it in the correct variable.